# Download monthly crash reports from google developer console by programmatically

Tags: crash-reports, google-developers-console

Is any possibilities to download the crash reports by programmatically from the google play developer console? Please help.

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any idea for this. Why don't u try gsutil commands?

Comment: Thanks david :).. I have tried this. But i need to know is there any possibilities to implement it in java.